# eval on expression of ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs

I would like to access a scope expression, that is assigned to a variable, through a ng-repeat expression.

So, what I wanna do is something like that:

```
ng-repeat="variable in eval(key)"
```

Unfortunately it is not valid. How can I workaround this?

Comment: What do you mean? This works: http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/BHA6M/

Comment: right, but I want something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/AmyyZ/1/

Comment: Remember it's scope.$eval, not scope.eval. Have to put the $.  I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $eval(key)">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.key = "items";
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/n5h4U/

(edited, see comments)

Comment: I didn't know the existence of $eval, or how to use it. thanks again!
But, actually, I think that right and direct answer would be a little different, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3PGsV/1/

Comment: Yeah, I just did the ng-init to keep it succint.

Comment: I agree.. although it doesn't answer the question of ngrepeat.
I accepted your answer, 'cause it was enough to me, but I think it would be better for future visitors if you edit the answer.